# Incompatible types error in ArrayList but both are String

Tags: java, arraylist, incompatibletypeerror

I'm fairly new to Java so don't attack me lol but I've created two classes and an ArrayList in one of them. I can't compile and get this error: `"incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int"` but nothing is being converted here? 
First class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class TestScores {
 private ArrayList < Class > scores;
 public int studentScores;
 public TestScores() {
  scores = new ArrayList < Class > ();
 }
 public void add(String name, int score) {
  scores.add(new Class(name, score));
 }
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class Class {
 public int score;
 public String name;
 public Class(int aScore, String aName) {
  score = aScore;
  name = aName;
 }
}
```

Comment: You messed up you constructor call for class with the order of parameters.
`public Class(int aScore, String aName)`. You pass first the `string` and then the `int` in `scores.add(new Class(name, score));`.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: You must reverse your parameters : new Class (score, name)

Comment: What do you think `new Class(name, score)` does?

Comment: See Chris Kitching's answer below. ***Don't*** call your class `Class`. It is bad form especially as it is part of `package java.lang` and is automatically included in all files.

Comment: @CoralieB it makes sense that they can't be reversed, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't call a class `Class`. There's a built-in class called `Class`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

While it's *allowed*, it's just unclear. Get into the habit of giving things descriptive names.

Your error is caused by the arguments being backwards. You construct a new Class like:

`new Class(name, score)`

But your constructor expects score first, then name:

`public Class(int aScore, String aName)`

Arguments in Java, unlike they sometimes are in Python, are matched by *position* not name. So you tried to bind the local String `name` to the int parameter `aScore`, hence the compile error.

Comment: I renamed it. I just typed this up real quick didn't even think about the naming convention. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

either change your constructor to

```
public Classname( String aName, int aScore,)
{
    score = aScore;
    name = aName;
}
```

your constructor accepts first integer and then string, but you are passing string first.

Answer (score 0):

`public Class(int aScore, String aName)` receives first parameter `int` and second `String`, but you send it vice versa.

In `scores.add(new Class(name, score));` you send the `String` first and the `int` second. It should be

```
scores.add(new Class(score, name));
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a small mistake I didn't even notice